# clearing page cache on Rails production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, production-environment, spree

I've inherited a Rails/Spree project that needs some changes, Rails version 2.3.8. I'm a newbie and am starting with the static pages as I thought those would be easiest, but I cannot see my changes.

What I've tried:

- In the content_controller.rb, I commented out the line: caches_page
  :show, :index, :if => Proc.new { Spree::Config[:cache_static_content]
- rake tmp:cache:clear
- rake db:sessions:clear
- the only log I could find was development.log, which was in a releases dir by date.  Can't find production.log
- there's nothing in the /tmp dir.

Any thoughts would be helpful. From what I can tell this project is set up in a non-Rails way (i.e. inline styles and javascript in the view files).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What server are you running on? Thin, Passenger or Unicorn?

Answer (score 0):

if there were pages cached with cache_page, they will be saved as HTML and served from the `public` directory. So if you have a content_controller#show action, most likely it is saved under `public/contents/#{id}.html`.

Comment: So I'm not seeing the page cached in public/, so I guess it's not being cached... so why can't I see my changes?

Comment: Figured it out... had to restart rails server through Phusion Passenger.